# Laravel: Add library (Particles.js) and load .json config (particles.json)

Tags: laravel, particles.js

I am learning Laravel (using `Laravel 8.x`). I don't understand how to integrate the package (`particles.js`) in the project correctly.

To be more specific, I have problems loading the `.json` file (ERR 404) from the project folder.

**Installation**

Already installed `particlesJS` (https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) in npm with

```
npm install particles.js
```

**Usage**

I Added the follow components to the view (`index.blade.html`)

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="particles.js"></script>
```

I added this code to `resources/app.js`

```js
/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

But I don't know where to save the `.json` file to load correctly from the script.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do what you are looking for. A brief explanation is that it loads the particle.js lib in the app.js along with the bootstrap require and loads the config from the public direct shown below, then you add the HTML head data that the script requires to run. lastly, you add the div to the body and it will load.

resources/js/app.js

```js
require('./bootstrap');
import 'particles.js/particles';
const particlesJS = window.particlesJS;

// JSON file is located in the directory of 'public/js/particlejs-config.json'
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'js/particlesjs-config.json', function() {
    console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

index.blade.html

```html
<head>
    ...
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <div id="particles-js">
        rest of html
    </div>
</body>
```